# How to send a message when a new user joins the server in the system messaging channel?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have this code:

```
class member_greeting(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self):
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        await guild.system_channel.send("I'm ready to go!")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(member_greeting(bot))
```

Does not send messages to the system messaging channel
How to write correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.on_guild_join) events have a [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) argument:

```py
class member_greeting(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        await guild.system_channel.send("I'm ready to go!")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(member_greeting(bot))
```

If you want your bot to send a message in every server it is in when it joins a new guild, I believe you have to use `async for guild in self.bot.guilds:` instead of `for guild in self.bot.guilds`:

```py
class member_greeting(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self):
        async for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            await guild.system_channel.send("I'm ready to go!")

    def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(member_greeting(bot))
```

Comment: Still, such a question how to make so that the creator from the server could set the channel where messages will be sent when the new user will join the server? I can reset some of the code. Is it better to create a new question and ask it there?

Comment: Yes, it's a whole new question. You should try using json or databases, iif it's too complicated, you can simply use python dictionnaries. Try to come up with some code before creating a question, otherwise, it would be downvoted ;)